# Successor of int32

Tags: c#, int

What is an immediate inheritor of int32 in C#?  Is it int or int16?

By inheritance, I mean given `class A : B {}` then class A is my class, and class B is a class that I inherit.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "successor"?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "inheritor"?

Comment: class A : B {}
 class A is my class, and class B i mean inheritor - its a class that i inherite

Comment: Are you asking about the base class for int32? That seems to be what you're talking about. In that case, Jon Skeet's answer is correct.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're talking about inheritance (it's not terribly clear)...

`System.ValueType`, effectively - or nothing, depending on your viewpoint.

Note that `int` and `System.Int32` are the same type; the first is an alias for the other.

Value types (such as `int`) implicitly inherit from `System.ValueType` (or `System.Enum`) and can't inherit from anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The basetype is `ValueType`.
Additionally it implements the interfaces `IComparable`, `IComparable<int>`, `IConvertible`, `IEquatable<int>`, `IFormatable`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on the question, but C# has the following datatypes:

`System.Int16` (keyword `short` can be used), 16bit

`System.Int32` (keyword `int` can be used), 32bit

They are value types so neither can inherit from anything other than `System.ValueType`, there is no inheritance between the two.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`. Since `System.Int32` is a struct, it has no subtypes. Like all structs, its immediate supertype is `System.ValueType` (which itself has supertype `System.Object`.)

`Int16` (also known by the keyword `short`) is also a struct, so has no subtypes, and supertype `System.ValueType`. It has no type relation to `int` and `Int32`.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691141%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> All value types implicitly inherit from
>   the class System.ValueType, which, in
>   turn, inherits from class object.

Although I'm not exactly sure if I understood your question well. If you are looking for a child of Int32, I think there is none as indicated [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/Common_Type_System%E2%80%94Type_Unification).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question but `int` is just an alias for `Int32` so by the process of elimination the answer to your question is probably `int16`.